# How to read a JSX component inside a javascript code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx, message

I have this delete function :

```
  showDeleteConfirmation(value, id, index, thisHandler) {
    //const { extraitMP3 } = this.state;
    confirm({
      title: 'Voulez vous supprimer cette audio ?',
      content: '',
      okText: 'Oui, je confirme',
      okType: 'danger',
      cancelText: 'Non',
      onOk() {
        deleteMp3Request(id);
        var { extraitMP3 } = thisHandler.state;
        var array = [];
        for (var key in extraitMP3) {
          array.push(extraitMP3[key]);
        }
       // console.log('array',array)
        const result = array.map(d => ({ 
          ...d, 
          TypeMp3List: 
              Object.fromEntries(
                //console.log(Object.entries(d.TypeMp3List)),
                Object.entries(d.TypeMp3List).splice(index,id)
              ) 
        }))
        // console.log('result',result)
        thisHandler.setState({ extraitMP3: result })
        NotificationManager.success("le fichier audio est supprimé avec succès !", "");
      },
      onCancel() {
      },
    });
  }
```

I want to replace the text messages with :

```
  title: <IntlMessages id="message.required.titresuppressionmp3" />,
  content: '',
  okText: <IntlMessages id="message.required.confirmation" />,
  okType: <IntlMessages id="message.required.danger" />,
  cancelText: <IntlMessages id="message.required.non"/>,
```

I did the import but it's not working correctly What should I do exactly to be read successfully. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: can you post where are you importing IntlMessages from

Answer (score 0):

The browsers doesn't support `JSX`, so you must use `babel` to convert the JSX into understandable for the browser javascript code. Check this [tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/)